# How to apply Geopy in a pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, map-function, geopy, nominatim

My DataFrame `'df'` has a column `df['Cidade']` with cities names and I want to find out the latitute and longitude of every single city using Geopy. The following code works for a single city input:

```
address='Pacoti'
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="Your_Name")
location = geolocator.geocode(address)
print(location.address)
print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
```

output:

> Pacoti, Região Geográfica Imediata de Redenção-Acarape, Região
> Geográfica Intermediária de Fortaleza, Ceará, Região Nordeste,
> 62770-000, Brasil (-4.2253561, -38.9208352)

So I tried to create a function:

```
def lat_long(x):
  address= x
  geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="Your_Name")
  location = geolocator.geocode(address)
  return location.latitude, location.longitude
```

then I used `'map'` function:

```
df['Cidade'].map(lat_long)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'latitude'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There may be a "bad" entry in that dataframe as you're mapping them all in which is giving you a none object when going for the objects lat and long. Check to see if this is case and give you an idea for fixing it:

```
if location is none:
  print("something")
```

Comment: thanks! How to convert a NoneType to string?